# Component two-way property binding... Tri Sate checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to build a triple state checkbox component.
Initially the checkbox value is null and is represented by an `indeterminate` checkbox.
When user clicks an indeterminate checkbox the value becomes true, next click false and then again null.

So far this is what I have:

```js
Vue.component('checkbox', {
        template: '<input type="checkbox" @change="change" class="checkbox-input">',
        props: ['currentSate'],
        mounted: function () {
            this.currentSate = null;
            this.$el.indeterminate = true
        },
        methods: {
            change: function () {
                if (this.currentSate == null) {
                    this.currentSate = true;
                    this.$el.checked = true;
                    this.$el.indeterminate = false;
                    return;
                }

                if (this.currentSate == true) {
                    this.currentSate = false
                    this.$el.checked = false;
                    this.$el.indeterminate = false;
                    return;
                }

                if (this.currentSate == false) {
                    this.currentSate = null;
                    this.$el.indeterminate = true;
                    return;
                }
                this.$emit('input', this.currentSate);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
        <checkbox v-bind:current-sate="chState"></checkbox>
                chState = {{chState}}
```

the error I'm getting is:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "currentSate"

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers were complete
So here it is.

```js
Vue.component('checkbox', {
        template: '<input type="checkbox" @change="change" class="checkbox-input">',
        props: ['value'],
        mounted: function () {
            this.value = null;
            this.$el.indeterminate = true
        },
        methods: {
            change: function () {
                if (this.value == null) {
                    this.$emit('input', true);
                    return;
                }

                if (this.value == true) {
                    this.$emit('input', false);
                    return;
                }

                if (this.value == false) {
                    this.$el.indeterminate = true;
                    this.$emit('input', null);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var myApp = new Vue(
        {
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                chState: null,
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <checkbox v-model="chState"></checkbox>
        chState = {{chState}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get this error, in a nutshell you need to *emit the value you want, but let the parent set it so it flows back down through the property*.

## More Info

You send an event up to the parent using `@emit`, the parent changes the property bound to `:value` or `:currentSate` in your case, and that in turn updates the child.

The way `v-model` works is that an input in changes in the child, 
 it fires an `@input` event, the parent receives it and modified the bound `:value`, and that goes back down to the child.

It seem a bit tedious, but in the end it eliminates a whole series of design issues.

## Solution

So in your case, you should not modify `currentSate`.  Just `@emit` the new value, and **not** modify `currentSate`.  Let the parent modify whatever `data` is bound to `:currentSate` and that will modify the property `currentSate`.

I advise you to use `value` instead of `currentSate` to follow the Vue conventions.  If you emit `input` and receive `value`, `v-model` will work out of the box.

## For Tri State Box

You can listen to 'click', and then switch on the value of the property 'currentSate'. Simply emit the next value based on the current value. You still need to let the parent update the bound value.

```js
onClick(value){
  switch(this.currentSate){
    case null: this.$emit('input', true); break;
    case true: this.$emit('input', false); break;
    case false: this.$emit('input', null); break;
  }
}
```

Here is an example of listening to the event and updating the bound property:

```html
<checkbox v-bind:current-sate="chState" @input='chState=$event'></checkbox>
```

Now, if you emit `input` and bind to `:value` instead of `currentSate`, you can do this:

```html
<checkbox v-model="chState"></checkbox>
```

`v-model` works when you use the convention of emitting your value as `input` and accepting your property as `value`.

Comment: But I need to modify the current state in order to know what value assign it on the next click

Comment: I will add some more info in solution.

Comment: This can be simplified `onClick() { this.$emit('input', this.currentState } }`

Comment: I no longer get the error, but nothing happens on the parent, Can you post a full js/html example? Maybe on jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: @boruchsiper I updated the solution with the logic to mutate the backing value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes up because you are mutating the prop directly from the child component.

`v-model` is definitely the way to go, however the state management can be handled in a far more elegant way.

I would recommend using a custom directive to enforce the `indeterminate` state of the checkbox when its inserted into the DOM. [Here](https://codepen.io/dormenog/pen/aMpGdv) you can find a code pen with a working example.

In a nutshell, it will look like this:

```js
Vue.directive('indeterminate', (el, binding) => {
  if (el.type && el.type === "checkbox" && binding.value === null) {
    el.indeterminate = true;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    checked: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    onInput($event) {
      this.checked = this.checked === false ? null : this.checked === true ? false : true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  I am {{ checked === null ? 'NULL' : checked }}
  <input type="checkbox" v-indeterminate="checked" :checked="checked" @input="onInput">
</div>
```

Update:

Updated to handle three states in a cycle. A simple solution is to handle the sequence of state in the `onInput` and to update the directive on every change.

Comment: The checkbox never goes back to indeterminate state on subsequent clicks in this example.

Comment: True @boruchsiper, I've updated the answer to keep the code minimal with no temporary state

Comment: The update works, but the logic happens in the app, not child component. This is supposed to be a working tri-state checkbox component out of the box.

Comment: Ok I think you are missing the point here. What I suggest is the use of a directive to handle the state rather than using a component to wrap up just the checkbox. Moving the logic into a component is trivial. Directives are means to extend HTML attributes to comply with the data driven approach, a component for this is an overkill.